# Taking previous screen fragment data on next screen fragment, how to clear that data?

Tags: android

Android Taking previous screen fragment data on next screen fragment, how to clear that data?

I am using one fragment A and on click of location option i am opening a location screen, but on location screen it opens previous screen options sometimes in blank area click.

In QUickSetUpLessonFragment on location click-
  @OnClick(R.id.liLocation)
    public void onLocationClick() {

```
    HomeGolfCourseSearchFragment fragment = new HomeGolfCourseSearchFragment();
    fragment.setTargetFragment(this, HOME_GC_CALLBACK_CODE);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.clQuickSetupActivity, fragment, "HomeGolfCourseSearchFragment").addToBackStack("HomeGolfCourseSearchFragment").commit();
}
```

I have opened HomeGolfCourseSearchFragment.
But on this fragment its giving some options of previous screen after clicking anywhere.[image]

Comment: Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

*Override* this method in your fragment activity

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // Refresh your fragment here          
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        Log.i("IsRefresh", "Yes");
    }
}
```

`

set

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pager_count);
```

happy_coding:)

Comment: set viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pager_count);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding clickable=true and focusable=true property to parent of each xml layout.